# Symfony 4 Translation - Issues with transChoice using MoFileLoader

Tags: php, symfony, translation, multilingual

We have a `.po` file that is converted into a `.mo` file for use with the [Symfony 4 Translations library](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html). We are experiencing issues when using the `transChoice` method.

Here's what's in the original `.po` file.

```
msgid "%count% person has been updated successfully!"
msgid_plural "%count% people have been updated successfully!"
msgstr[0] "%count% person har blitt oppdatert!"
msgstr[1] "%count% personer har blitt oppdatert!"
```

We have cache turned on and when the cached PHP file loads, it converts the above to the following:

```
'%count% person has been updated successfully!' => '%count% person har blitt oppdatert!',
'%count% people have been updated successfully!' => '{0} %count% person har blitt oppdatert!|{1} %count% personer har blitt oppdatert!',
```

It seems the plural has the singular and plural versions. Is that correct and should I always use the plural form for the `$id` when using the `transChoice` method?

e.g: do this

```
$this->translator->transChoice(
    '%count% people have been updated successfully!', 
    5, 
    array(
        '%count%' => 5
    )
);
```

... instead of this

```
$this->translator->transChoice(
    '%count% person has been updated successfully!|%count% people have been updated successfully!', 
    5, 
    array(
        '%count%' => 5
    )
);
```